# How do i use 2 separate functions "fgets" for writing into 2 separate variables?

Tags: c, fgets, fputs

I've got a code:

```
 char *text, *key;
 char str[200];
 fputs("Please, enter the text, you want to encrypt:", stdout);
 printf("\n");
 if((text=fgets(str, sizeof(str),stdin))!=NULL)
 {
     printf("Text to encrypt:\n""");
     fputs(text, stdout);
     printf("""\n");
 }


 fputs("Please, enter the key:", stdout);
 printf("\n");
 if((key=fgets(str, sizeof(str),stdin))!=NULL)
 {
     printf("Key:\n""");
     fputs(key, stdout);
     printf("""\n");
 }
```

I made it that way, because I wanted to write into variable "text" at first, and then, after succesful writing, write into another variable. However, instead I can only write variable "text", but not variable "key", and text is shown wrong way. How do I fix this? (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: `fgets` is writing into `str` in both cases. Then it sets `text` and `key` to point to `str`. If you want two different variables, you need two different arrays.

Comment: `char text[200], key[200];` and lose `str` entirely.

Comment: Certain you want `\n\"` and not `\n""`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets` writes into the string that's its first argument. Since you were using the same string, the second `fgets` was overwriting the string from the first one. You need two strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char text[200], key[200];
    fputs("Please, enter the text, you want to encrypt:", stdout);
    printf("\n");
    if(fgets(text, sizeof(text),stdin)!=NULL)
        {
            printf("Text to encrypt:\n""");
            fputs(text, stdout);
            printf("""\n");
        }


    fputs("Please, enter the key:", stdout);
    printf("\n");
    if(fgets(key, sizeof(key),stdin)!=NULL)
        {
            printf("Key:\n""");
            fputs(key, stdout);
            printf("""\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: OK, thank you, now it should be written. But instead I've got picture like that in console: http://gyazo.com/eaa6800025f2e6ddcc0f55b4d1a9ae23.png
It jumps from field for writing "text" to the "key field. But I want them to be shown separately: "text" first, then, only after writing - "key".

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you have code before this that reads input? It may be leaving a newline in the input, and the first `fgets` is reading that.

Comment: Yes have code before given one (starting from "fputs"), here it is:  `int main() {  
   int option;  
   char *text, *key;

    text=malloc(200*sizeof(char));
    key=malloc(200*sizeof(char));
    

    make_deck();//Creating a deck

    printf("Choose option:\n  1. Encryption\n  2. Decryption\n ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    printf("\n\n");

    switch(option) {

 case 1:
    printf("Choose option:\n  1. Enter\n  2. File\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    printf("\n\n");
    switch(option) {

    case 1:
`

Comment: `scanf` doesn't read the newline. Use `fgets` to read the input, and then `sscanf` to get the number from it.

Comment: I use `scanf` for scaning `option` for the `switch`. So that's the reason?